# 1st and 2nd derivative test of max-min

Tags: maxima-minima

Is there any situation where 1st derivative test is preferred over 2nd derivative test or 2nd derivative test preferred over 1st derivative test? Or do they prefer equivalently?

I have been running across so many problem where the two test can simultaneously used.So I am wondering if there is any situation where I have to choose between the two carefully.

Comment: In generale you need both of them to understand what kind of point you are facing with.

Comment: I prefer 1st derivative test. For some functions, computing the second derivative can be time-consuming, and the task of finding the zeros of the 1st derivative is almost as hard than studying the sign.

Comment: @ajotatxe yeah. I have been using both the tests according to the form of the function and the critical points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in general, when derivatives exist:

> if $f'(x_0)=0$ and $\exists k \geq 2$ s.t. $f^k(x_0) \neq 0$ then

- when the least of those **k is even** you have a max/min in $x_0$ (depending on the sign)
- when the least of those **k is odd** you have an inflection point in $x_0$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks! I've improved the recipe!

Comment: Got it@gimusi. This is more precise. Thanks for ur time.